# How do I get google maps to display nearby restaurants?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, search

I am trying to create a site that uses Google Maps API to search for restaurants near to the users location. I don't want it to load on start up, I will add a button that will initiate the search. This is the code I have. I am getting a map but there are no markers and no restaurants being shown. I have a Places API enabled and a div with `id="map:` in my body. Why am I not seeing the restaurants?

```
var map;

function createMap(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 40.0519752, lng: -76.314270999999},
    zoom: 10 
  });



var request ={
  location: center,
  radius: 8047,
  types: ['cafe']
}

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if(status ==google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  })
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', createMap);

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY&callback=createMap&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `ReferenceError: center is not defined`

Guessing you want that to be the map's center (`map.getCenter()`)

If I make that change, your code returns 20 places with type `cafe`

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f42qdy39/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function createMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.0519752,
      lng: -76.314270999999
    },
    zoom: 10
  });

  var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 8047,
    types: ['cafe']
  }

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name
  })
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=createMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `center` is not defined in the PlacesService request. That is the only issue I see with the code.